# Why does the backspace key print ^? when calling gets() in crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

When I try to correct input for my crystal program (in a zsh terminal on my Mac), a ^? character is printed to the screen for each press of backspace. It's disorienting and does not delete any characters from the screen, but it technically functions just fine as I discovered playing around with this little testing snippet.

```
a = gets.as(String).chomp
puts a
a = gets   # alright then^?^?^?^?^?
puts a     # alright
```

What is going on here? How can I make my input behave as a user would expect, is there something special I can do with STDIN?

Comment: Can't confirm this behaviour for `zsh-5.8.1` on linux, so this issue might be osx related?

Comment: That's useful to know, thank you js-on!

Comment: I don't see how this is related to zsh, in particular since I don't see any zsh code in your question. It seems that the library which processes user input, does not know what to do with a backspace. Maybe you can use `rlwrap`. This was written originally with Linux in mind, but if you google for _rlwrap macos_, a few hits will come up.

Comment: I wasn't sure if this was happening because I was using zsh. It turns out, no, it's not related, so I removed the tag from the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it will depend on the terminal that you are using and it is largely independent of the programming language (e.g. it has been [reported in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8976452/783510)).

Some terminals send `^H` or `^?` when you type a backslash. I can also reproduce it in `xterm` (on Linux) when calling `cat`, which is roughly similar to getting a line and printing it (in a loop):

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm

$ cat
abc^H^H^Hdef
def
```

... while it works with other terminals (same test: typing `abc`, deleting three characters, then typing `def`):

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color

$ cat
def
def
```

You can use libraries like readline to workaround around it. I have not tried it myself, but this library implements bindings for Crystal: [crystal-readline](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal-readline)

Comment: That's super interesting! I wasn't aware of that library, so I took it for a spin and it seems to handle backspaces on my system perfectly, as well as not print ctrl + key symbols. Thank you for the recommendation!